# Can do smoothing after making time-series data stationary

Tags: time-series, stationarity, smoothing

Can do smoothing after making time-series data stationary? And is it useful to do smoothing before making data stationary?

Comment: What is your analytical objective and why do you need stationarity?  As far as smoothing goes, if you smooth strongly enough, the series will flatten out to a straight line, which is as stationary as it can get ;-).